# Java ObjectProperty dynamically get setter function

Tags: java, reflection, javafx, properties

Say I have a SimpleObjectProperty, and has a setter function named set. Is there another way to get the setter function from the object than searching for a function with the right name?

I figured, since Oracle says a property called firstName should have a setter called setFirstName, perhaps there is a faster and more convenient way of finding it? I would prefer calling object.setValue to call the setter, but that would require overriding of the SimpleObjectProperty class I guess.

Comment: how would you know if the method is actually setting some value?

Comment: JSON/database/.. pojo mapping typically allows you to attach annotations to arbitrary getters/setters instead of having to follow naming convention. That's probably a way it could have been implemented.

Comment: Can you clarify? The scenario is that you have a reference to an `ObjectProperty`, and you want to know the object to which that property belongs and the name of the `setXXX(...)` method in that object that will invoke the `set(...)` method in the `ObjectProperty`, is that correct? (And if so, why?).

Comment: @James_D Yes. I have a table with properties that are rendered in certain ways to be editable, for example one might be a drop-down list. When the value is changed, it invokes <property_name>.set() with the new value.

However, I do some validation and some observer notifications in the setXXX()-method, and do not want it to surpass that. I also don't want the observers to have to directly listen to every single property of the object.